# Receive a HTTP request for all messages in a Skype group conversation with an Azure Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, skype

I have a working Skype bot working via the Azure Bot. In Azure, under Resource > Configuration, the bot is configured to send incoming messages to a "Messaging endpoint".

This works well for 1:1 messages, and bot mentions (with @) in a group. However I want to get a webhook request for all messages where the bot is added, even when it is not mentioned.

Is this possible?

I found some documentation on how to do this in Microsoft Teams, but I am not sure how to do it in Skype:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-messages-with-rsc?tabs=channel%2Cdotnet

I have also found this thread that basically says that is not possible, not sure if it is still relevant:

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4046

Comment: This feature is not available due to privacy reasons. Bots in a group chat only receive messages directly addressed to them.

Comment: @JayashankarGS it is possible with SkPy, via an unofficial Skype API (probably the one used by web.skype). Bummer, that Microsoft are not allowing this via the official Bot Framework, it makes it more difficult to integrate Skype with other platforms.